# YACC and Context Free Grammars

Tags: compiler-errors, yacc

I'm not able to derive a yacc program for the following problem.

The grammar for strings having equal number of a's and b's is as follows

S -> a S b S | b S a S | epsilon

I was wondering if it is possible to make a YACC program for it. Also while making the code, i realised what if the input does not have equal a and b. Where in YACC should i print some message indicating the string was invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yacc` implements a parser for an `LALR(1)` grammar; the grammar (and, I believe, the language) are not `LALR(1)`. (This is related to my first point below.)

If you use `bison` (which is likely), then you could generate a GLR grammar using the `%glr` option, in which case a naive transliteration of the grammar would work. However, you will encounter two problems:

1. Most valid strings have multiple parses, and bison's GLR parsers insist that the final result not be ambiguous. I don't know if there is a simple solution to this using `%dprec`, but its possible.
2. You can't tell that a string doesn't match the grammar until you reach the end of the string, since any string is a prefix of a valid string. (You only have to add enough of the minority symbols to achieve equality.)